# Turn point cloud into rasterized mesh with PDAL-C and it's API

Tags: raster, c#, pdal, mesh, laz

I'm triyng to turn a point cloud into a mesh that's rasterized like the code in c# below describes but I have come to the problem that the filter delaunay does not work with a raster, only with a point cloud.
I've tried to get the raster points with the api in order to make the mesh myself but I cannot get the points (maybe I'm missing something)

I'm using PDAL-C inside Unity (wich is exactly the same as without Unity)
This is the code I've written:

```
List<object> pipes = new List<object>();
pipes.Add(fileInfo.FullName); // Point cloud
pipes.Add(new { type = "filters.range", limits = "Classification[2:2]" }); // Point cloud
pipes.Add(new { type = "filters.delaunay" }); // Mesh
pipes.Add(new { type = "filters.faceraster", resolution = 1 }); // Raster
pipes.Add(new { type = "filters.delaunay" }); // Mesh (does not work)

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pipes);
Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline(json);
pipeline.Execute();

PointViewIterator pointViewIterator = pipeline.Views;
pointViewIterator.Reset();

while (pointViewIterator.HasNext())
{
    PointView pointView = pointViewIterator.Next;

    if (pointView != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(pointView.getMesh().VertexCount);
    }
}
```

I could work with either a mesh generated by PDAL-C or the raster points and make the mesh myself
Maybe there is a filter that turns a raster (GDAL) into a point cloud bit I cannot find it (if it exists).

Comment: Seems like in the first three steps of the pipeline you are filtering out the ground points, fitting a mesh to the ground, then rasterizing the mesh to create a DEM layer. What is the purpose of the fourth step? I'm not sure why you would want to interpolate a points layer from a grid layer, as even if it is accomplished you will lose resolution compared to the original mesh.

Comment: With the four step I try to create a mesh with the points of the raster. It is not necessary but I need a mesh of known size. The problem is that once I apply the faceraster filter, the point cloud turns into a raster; and the mesh filter does not seem to work with a raster. I could also create the mesh myself but I cannot access the pixels of the raster from the API (maybe I'm missing some method or class that let's me access the pixels from the API)